# string.split() and dealing with duplicates

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string `String test = "-b--b--";`

I want an array that has `{"", "b", "", "b", ""}`

How can I call the `string.split()` function to obtain this?

EDIT:

I've tried `test.split("-")`.
My tests gave me `{"", "b", "", "b"}`.
Why does the method not include the last emptyspace on my array if it did include the first one between the first pair of hyphens?

Basically I want to get all the characters between the hypens, where `String test = ---` should give me `{"", "", ""}`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You need to make an explicit statement for what you're trying to achieve. For example, you could qualify the above by saying something like "I want to extract all occurencces of "b" with all intermediary characters replaced with an empty string, But then what do you want to do with "bb"?

Comment: In `split(regex)` method *Trailing empty strings are not included in the resulting array* (from JavaDoc). You are looking for `split` version with `limit` option and use negative limit as argument, like `split("-",-1)`.

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah sorry about that it's been a long day. I was in the middle of editing my thread. I've edited it now for more clarity.

Comment: You want all characters between `hyphens`, then `---` should return `{"", ""}` instead?

Comment: @user2280704 Could you explain why `b--` after split should give `{"b", ""}` but `---` should give `{"","",""}`?

Answer (score 1):

Its mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> Trailing empty strings not included in the resulting array.

---

For the desired result change it to

```
test.split("-",Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This would consider empty strings and so the output would be

```
"", "b", "", "b", "" , ""
```

Comment: Did you test the code? The output wouldn't be what you have shown. There will be two empty string at the end.

Comment: @RohitJain ohh..yes indeed..but that should be the expected result and op can avoid the last result(if empty) every time provided he doesn't need it..

Answer (score 0):

you can try `.getCharAt()` method of string to your problem.
The following code can help:

```
char test1[]=new char[test.length()];
for(int i=0;i<test.length();i++)
if(test.getCharAt(i)=='-')
test1[i]=' ';
else
test[i]=test.getCharAt(i);
```

hope this will help you....